# How can I login to index.php and have slightly different content being displayed in it from when I am not?

Tags: php, html

Since the question is a bit vague and unclear, I will clarify what I mean in the following sentences.

The main page of my website is called index3.php and in there, there is the appropriate log in form which requires username and password fields for the user to log in.

What I am trying to do but I couldn't manage yet, is on submit to be redirected in index3.php but instead of the log-in form to see text saying "Logged-in as:" in the log-in div. In other words replacing the form with Dynamic Text in the same div the form was in previously. Currently what it does is to redirect you to another page called login.php.

here is the php-code of the index3.php

```
   <?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
$password=($_POST['password']);
$MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "login.php";
$MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index3.php";
$MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
mysql_select_db($database_ideatedb, $ideatedb);

$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

$LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $ideatedb) or die(mysql_error());
$loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
?>
```

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line determines where you are redirected:

```
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "login.php";
```

So if you want to go to `index3.php`, just change `login.php` to `index3.php`.

Then, you'll have to alter `index3.php` to display the signed-in message instead of the login form. As far as I can tell, this happens in a part of the file you haven't supplied, but the basic idea would probably be like this:

```
<aside>
  <?php if ($_SESSION['MM_Username']): ?>
    hello, you're signed in as <?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    ...existing login form in index3.php...
  <?php endif; ?> 
</aside>
```

(In case you're confused by the lack of curly braces, I used the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), because it's *slightly* nicer when writing [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).)

Comment: I did follow your instructions and putted the appropriate form code inside the else statement, but all that happens when I am logging in now is being redirected to index3.php with the login form empty. I am not sure if it affects the code or not but my form is inside an <aside> tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Azu: The `aside` tag shouldn't affect this, but the styling used to display the form might. Can you view source in your browser to see what's inside the `aside` tag after you log in? (Also, i've edited my answer based on your input...)

Comment: Well first of all thanks for adjusting your example :) secondly inside the aside is still the initial form even after I am logging in. It's like I never logged out and I just redirected to index3.php on submit without any changes

Comment: @Azu: Hmm... I don't see where `$loginStrGroup` gets set, so maybe it's the problem. How about if you modify the condition to only check for `$_SESSION['MM_Username']`? I've updated my answer accordingly. If that doesn't work, perhaps try a `var_dump ($_SESSION)` inside the form branch of the if statement...

Comment: Just a clarification, according to my code, shall I remove any bits of it, and just place the code inside the <aside> tag? or just leave everything as it is and put the code you provided in the <aside> tag as well? PS: When I am using only the $_SESSION['MM_Username'] it automatically has me logged in the website.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
       echo "Logged in as " . $_SESSION['user'];
   }
?>
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: No no I know how to do this part, I just don't know how I can force the index3.php to redirect me in the same page which is index3.php after I am logged in, but having modified html code in it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are redirected is due to thee last few lines here

```
if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
```

If you change it to something like this

```
<div id="formHolder">
<?php
    if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    echo "You are logged in"; //You can customize this message using the users username
    }
    else { ?>
    You would put your html form in here
    <?php}
    }?>
```

This is a really crap way of doing this kind of thing. Remember that just because it works doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't improve it :)

Comment: How is it possible though to alter the html code of the same page? To be more specific how can I change the content and instead of the content form to get the Dynamic text instead in the same div, once I am redirected back to index3.php of course.

Comment: you could just put the code I modified into the div that shows the form check out the edit above.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to put the code above in the form div right? and all the appropriate html form code in the else statement, if I got that right :)

Comment: yeah, you could do that. Its worth checking out the comment below by @grossvogel he used alternative syntax for the control structures which will make it easier to read your code once you make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($_SESSION['seclevel']){
  case "One security level":
    include('oneseclevel.php');
    break;
  case "Other security level":
    include('otherseclevel.php');
    break;
  default:
    include('login.php');
}
```